# How to store Table data in a csv using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I just cant´t get my head around how I should go about.

All I want to do is, to extract all the table data an store them in a csv file. I got the data from the table, but I am struggling to format the data, so that I can write them to a csv file.

Help or advise on how to tackle this one is much apreciated.

This is the HTML:

```html
  <div id="wpgmza_marker_holder_3" class='wpgmza_marker_holder'
   style="width:100%;">
<table id="wpgmza_table_3" class="wpgmza_table responsive" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='wpgmza_table_marker'><strong></strong></th>
      <th class='wpgmza_table_title
      all'><strong>Bezeichnung</strong></th>
      <th class='wpgmza_table_category'><strong>Kategorie</strong></th>
      <th class='wpgmza_table_address'><strong>Adresse</strong></th>
      <th class='wpgmza_table_description'><strong>Beschreibung</strong></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="wpgmza_marker_1346" mid="1346" mapid="3" class="wpgmaps_mlist_row">
      <td class='wpgmza_table_marker' height="40"><img class="wpgmza_marker_icon " src="https://i1.wp.com/lebensmitteltechnik-deutschland.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Getränketechnik.png?w=584&#038;ssl=1" style="margin: 5px auto;" data-recalc-dims="1" /></td>
      <td class='wpgmza_table_title all'>100 Blumen Brauerei GmbH</td>
      <td class='wpgmza_table_category'>Getränketechnologie </td>
      <td class='wpgmza_table_address'>Endresstraße 18 1230 Wien, Österreich</td>
      <td class='wpgmza_table_description'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="wpgmza_marker_1187" mid="1187" mapid="3" class="wpgmaps_mlist_row">
      <td class='wpgmza_table_marker' height="40"><img class="wpgmza_marker_icon " src="https://i0.wp.com/lebensmitteltechnik-deutschland.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Lebensmitteltechnik.png?w=584&#038;ssl=1" style="margin: 5px auto;" data-recalc-dims="1" /></td>
      <td class='wpgmza_table_title all'>11er Nahrungsmittel GmbH</td>
      <td class='wpgmza_table_category'>Lebensmitteltechnik </td>
      <td class='wpgmza_table_address'>Galinastraße 34 6820 Frastanz, Österreich</td>
      <td class='wpgmza_table_description'></td>
    </tr>
```

```html
import os
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


f = csv.writer(open('outputFile.csv','w'))
f.writerow(['Company Name','Category','Adress'])

path = "C:/Users/trond/OneDrive/Dokumente/01 Tech/01 Python"
file_name = os.path.join(path, "text.txt")
my_file = open("text.txt", encoding="utf-8")
my_file_contents = my_file.read()


plain_text = my_file_contents
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")

for company_name in soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'wpgmza_table_title all'}):
    print(company_name.string)

for company_category in soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'wpgmza_table_category'}):
    print(company_category.string)
 
for company_address in soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'wpgmza_table_address'}):
    print(company_address.string)

    
f.writerow(['company_name.string','company_category.string', 'company_adress.string']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the company names, categories, and addresses in lists and then you can write the rows into the csv file.

I.e. you can save the company names in a list like this:

```
company_names = []
for company_name in soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'wpgmza_table_title all'}):
    company_names.append(company_name.string)
```

And then the categories and addresses:

```
company_categories = []
for company_category in soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'wpgmza_table_category'}):
    company_categories.append(company_category.string)

company_addresses = []
for company_address in soup.findAll('td', {'class': 'wpgmza_table_address'}):
    company_addresses.append(company_address.string)
```

And then you can use those lists to write the rows to your csv file using a for-loop:

```
for i in range(len(company_names)):
    f.writerow([company_names[i], company_categories[i], company_adresses[i]])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - Seems much easier than I thought!

Comment: Great! If it works, please mark the answer as "correct"!

Comment: I just tried it - and it didn´t quite work. The script only prints [company_names[i], company_categories[i], company_adresses[i]]). I am still figuring out why

Comment: I'm guessing you might have added some quotation marks in the `writerow` line.